# A statement about coprime actions in Kurzweil/Stellmacher text book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

A group $A$ acts on another group $G$ if every $a \in A$ corresponds to some automorphism of $G$, i.e., we have
$$
 g^1 = g, \qquad 
 g^{ab} = (g^a)^b \quad\mbox{and}\quad
 (gh)^a = g^a h^a
$$
for $g,h \in G$, $a,b \in A$ and $1 \in A$ denoting the identity element in $A$. An action is called coprime if the orders of $A$ and $G$ are coprime. 
Let $C_A(G) = \{ a \in A : g^a = g \mbox{ for all } g \in G \}$, the kernel of the action, we say that $A$ acts faithful if $C_A(G) = 1$.

In Kurzweil/Stellmacher *The Theory of finite groups* in chapter 8 about coprime action, they state as theorem 8.2.10

> Let $G$ be a $p$-group and $\mathcal K$ the set of all $A$-composition factors of $G$. Suppose that the action of $A$ on $G$ is coprime. Then
>   $$
>  \bigcap_{K\in \mathcal K} C_A(K) / C_A(G) = O_p(A / C_A(G)).
> $$

But by coprime action I guess we have $O_p(A) = 1$, hence the statement is the same as
$$
 \bigcap_{K\in \mathcal K} C_A(K) = C_G(A)
$$
or for a faithful action $\bigcap_{K\in \mathcal K} C_A(K) = 1$. Am I right, or am I missing something? Just wondering why it is stated in that ways that seems to complicated...

Comment: There's a typo in the second equality of your first display; the third $a$ should be a $b$.

Comment: I conjecture that there is a mistake in the book, and the authors did not intend to assume that the action is coprime. The result holds without that assumption.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you. Fixed it.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. Yes, that makes sense. Also in the proof it is not used that the action of $A$ is coprime, but that the action for some $p'$ subgroup is. Maybe just the assumption about coprime action in the statement was actually not intended.